# get current Logged in user name from within a C++ windows service

Tags: c++, windows

I have a service (written in C++), running under Windows 10. I need to get the name of the currently logged in user, but most Windows APIs I have found return the username of the *calling thread*, which when run as a system, is always "SYSTEM".

My use case is below:

- Install the service with Administrator account
- Log off from administrator
- Login as a Non-Admin user
- Query the service to get the current logged user name

Comment: "*I need to get the name of the currently logged in user*" - there can be more than 1 user logged in at a time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enumerate all sessions and identify the active session using `WTSEnumerateSessions`. Then you can query username of the active session using `WTSQuerySessionInformation` and query class `WTSUsername`.

```
WTS_SESSION_INFO *SessionInfo;
unsigned long SessionCount;
unsigned long ActiveSessionId = -1;

std::cout<<"Active Console Session Id : "<<WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId()<<"\n";

if(WTSEnumerateSessions(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, 0, 1, &SessionInfo, &SessionCount))
{
    for (auto i = 0; i < SessionCount; i++)
    {
        if (SessionInfo[i].State == WTSActive)
        {
            ActiveSessionId = SessionInfo[i].SessionId;
            break;
        }
    }

    char *UserName;
    if (ActiveSessionId != -1)
    {
        unsigned long BytesReturned;
        if (WTSQuerySessionInformation(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, ActiveSessionId, WTSUserName, &UserName, &BytesReturned))
        {
            std::cout<<UserName;
            WTSFreeMemory(UserName);
        }
    }

    WTSFreeMemory(SessionInfo);
}
```

Note that this will only work if there is only one active session (unlike terminal servers)

Comment: There can be more than 1 "active" session at a time, for instance if clients are allowed to login via Remote Desktop

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, that is why i have put a note at the end.

Answer (score 1):

in addition to answer above, the following line

```
 if (SessionInfo[i].State == WTSActive)
```

should be changed to

```
if (SessionInfo[i].State == WTSActive || SessionInfo[i].State == WTSConnected)
```

to include remote session too

Comment: Should be   

if (SessionInfo[i].State == WTSActive || SessionInfo[i].State == WTSConnected)